# Flask website repeating returned values when refreshing page

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a python program (port.py) that does some simple ETA calculations and returns a list of the values to Flask (app.py) which then prints them onto a basic html page (index.html)

The problem I am having, is that when I reload the page, all the existing data from the last calculation remains.  It does update the calculation for new times, but it just prints it all after the previous one.

I've spent all day trying to get it to clear the previous calculations and return the current values to a clean html page, not just simply repeat it all.

It all works, but it's just the formatting and getting a clean webpage for everytime you visit the site that is destroying me.

Here is the code from my port.py

```
import datetime
# from tabulate import tabulate
import timedelta
import sqlite3


class Port:
    def __init__(self, name, distance, sheet):
        self.name = name
        self.distance = distance
        self.sheet = sheet
        portlist.append(self)

    def time(self):
        i = ((48 - self.distance) / s * 3600)
        i = timedelta.Timedelta(seconds=i)
        return i

    def eta(self):
        k = self.time()
        # TODO: now needs changing to start time when inputting a start time
        k = k + start
        return k

    def tide(self):
        # connect to database
        conn = sqlite3.connect('pythonsqlite.db')
        conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        # create a cursor
        c = conn.cursor()
        # round the times
        r = self.eta()
        approx = round(r.minute / 10.) * 10
        r = r.replace(minute=0)
        r += datetime.timedelta(seconds=approx * 60)
        rounded = r.time()

        date = r.strftime('%d-%m-%y')
        time = rounded.strftime('%H:%M')
        # this is where to search the excel/sql file
        # TODO change basedata2 for a table depending on the port location
        c.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM basedata2 WHERE Date = '" + date + "'")
        f = c.fetchone()
        f = f[time]
        f = f / 100
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        return f

    def planned(self):
        p = self.eta()
        p = p.strftime("%H:%M")
        return p

    def ukc(self):
        u = self.tide() - d
        return u


s = 10

d = 5
# d = float(input('Draft: '))


start = datetime.datetime.now()
portlist = []


def createplan():
    Port("port1", 48.0, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port2", 42.9, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port3", 40.1, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port4", 38.0, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port5", 35.6, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port6", 33.4, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port7", 31.7, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port8", 31.4, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port9", 30.7, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port10", 27.7, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port11", 26.2, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port12", 24.7, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port13", 22.5, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port14", 19.7, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port15", 18.4, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port16", 11.8, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port17", 8.3, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port18", 6.3, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port19", 0, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port20", 5.2, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port21", 2.6, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port22", 1.7, 'Sheet1')
    Port("port23", 0, 'Sheet1')


# def createtable():
#     headers = ['Location', 'Time', 'Tide', 'UKC']
#     # TODO: rename these
#     tablename1 = []
#     tablename2 = []
#     tablename3 = []
#     tablename4 = []
#
#     for obj in portlist:
#         # print(obj.name, obj.planned(), obj.tide())
#         tablename1.append(obj.name)
#         tablename2.append(obj.planned())
#         tablename3.append(obj.tide())
#         tablename4.append(obj.ukc())
#
#     table = zip(tablename1, tablename2, tablename3, tablename4)
#     print(tabulate(table, headers=headers, tablefmt='github', floatfmt=".2f"))


def printportlist():
    createplan()
    location = []
    planned = []
    tidevalue = []
    ukc = []
    for obj in portlist:
        location.append(obj.name)
        planned.append(obj.planned())
        tidevalue.append(obj.tide())
        ukc .append(obj.ukc())
    return location, planned, tidevalue, ukc


def main():
    # createplan()
    # createtable()
    printportlist()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and here is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_moment import Moment
import datetime
import port

app = Flask(__name__)
moment = Moment(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', current_time=datetime.datetime.utcnow())


@app.route('/user/<name>')
def user(name):
    return render_template('user.html', name=name)


@app.route('/port')
def runport():
    return render_template('index.html', content=[port.printportlist()])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and here is the code from my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
    <title>Port Page Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Port Page Testing!</h1>
        {% for x in content %}
            <p>{{ x }}</p>
        {% endfor %}

    </body>
</html>
```

Really would appreciate any help.. I just can't seem to figure this one out.

EDIT: All code included

Comment: Show the code that produces `portlist`. There's likely a global list that isn't being cleared.

Comment: That's great Dave... Thank you..  Solved teh problem of the ever increasing lists. I've now just realised that my port.py doesn't get reloaded on each web refresh to recalculate the start time..  One step at a time.. Thanks for the help!